# initializing a vector of vector<doubles> c++

Tags: c++, vector

Hi I want to initialize a size 9 vector whose elements are vectors of the size, say 5. I want to initialize all the elements to the zero vector.

Is this way correct?

```
vector<double> z(5,0);

vector< vector<double> > diff(9, z);
```

OR is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: That is the correct way to create a 2D vector. You are just being a little more verbose is all.

Comment: Yes I know the sizes before hand. Just chose the 9 and 5 to be some random ints for this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could potentially do this in a single line:

```
vector<vector<double> > diff(9, vector<double>(5));
```

You might also want to consider using [boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) for more efficient storage and access (it avoids double pointer indirection).

Comment: Alternatively, a vector of 45 elements with strided access might suffice as well...

Comment: `vector<double>(5)` suffices. `vector<double>(5, 0)` is not required, as long as the second argument is `0`.

Answer (score 5):

You can put it all in one line:

```
vector<vector<double>> diff(9, vector<double>(5));
```

This avoids the unused local variable.

(In pre-C++11 compilers you need to leave a space, `> >`.)

Comment: Careful of the `>>` in your syntax. Some compilers require a space between those symbols.

Comment: @R.Martinho Fernandes: in that case there do not exist *any* conforming C++ implementations. At least, I don't believe that anybody has shipped a finished C++11 implementation yet. Deliberately writing code that won't compile is all very well to show your loyalty to the new standard, but in reality C++03 ain't dead yet. That said, I believe the major compilers have done this particular feature.

Comment: @SteveJessop Oh sure. That's why I used a :P smiley.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: yeah, that did come over a bit ranty. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

`vector< vector<double> > diff(9, std::vector<double>(5, 0));`

However in the specific case where the sizes are known at compile time you *could* use a C array:

`double diff[9][5] = { { 0 } };`

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure this will work:

```
vector< vector<double> > diff(9, vector<double>(5,0));
```

Answer (score 4):

If the sizes are fixed, you can go with `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<std::array<double,5>,9> diff = {};
```

Comment: It also depends on the magnitude of the extents. `std::array` keeps everything in the local scope, so if that array is too large, you could trigger some error whose name escapes me.